# PHP error: Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: javascript, php, json, html, pdo

i have created an api to fetch data from database to echo it as json and finally display it in html but while echoing the data,

i am getting below php errors

> Notice:  Undefined offset: 80 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ReadExchange/api.php on line 16
>
> Notice:  Undefined offset: 79 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ReadExchange/api.php on line 16
>
> Notice:  Undefined offset: 78 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ReadExchange/api.php on line 16

and so on,

**PHP Code**

```
$db_result_set = $db->prepare('SELECT p.Id, p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName, p.Gender, p.Location, p.Email, p.Mobile,b.BookTitle, b.BookGenre, b.BookWriter, b.BookDescription FROM personaldetails AS p LEFT JOIN bookdetails AS b ON b.UserId = p.Id ORDER BY p.Id DESC');;

$db_result_set->execute();

$final = [];
foreach ($db_result_set as $u) {

    if (!is_array($final[$u["Id"]])) {   //line 16 
        $final[$u["Id"]]= [
            "Id" => $u["Id"],
            "FirstName" => $u["FirstName"],
            "MiddleName" => $u["MiddleName"],
            "LastName" => $u["LastName"],
            "Gender" => $u["Gender"],
            "Location" => $u["Location"],
            "Email" => $u["Email"],
            "Mobile" => $u["Mobile"],
         ];
    }
    $final[$u["Id"]]["books"][] = [
        "BookTitle" => $u["BookTitle"],
        "BookGenre" => $u["BookGenre"],
        "BookWriter" => $u["BookWriter"],
        "BookDescription" => $u["BookDescription"],
    ];

}   
    
    header('Content-type: application/javascript');
    echo json_encode($final);
```

?>

i am not confirm but i think because of this i am not getting json data in html.

Comment: Use `if (!empty($final[$u["Id"]]))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: `header('Content-type: application/javascript');` ? What are you trying to echo? Do you mean `header('Content-type: application/json');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not: `if (!is_array($final[$u["Id"]]))`

but: `if (!isset($final[$u["Id"]]))`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check if an undefined offset exists in your array. You need to first need to check if the offset exists with [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

So change your code to

```
if (isset($final[$u["Id"]]) && ! is_array($final[$u["Id"]))
```